# Trim an audio file that is labelled with a timestamp c++

Tags: c++, audio-recording

So i have a program that records snippets of audio on a microphone array, it then timestamps the end time of the file. My problem is that the process of the program starting the recording takes a random amount of time to start and so the audio is a random length. I want a way to read the size of the file (kilobytes) then trim the file by a certain number of kilobytes so that the recordings are always the same length.

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "zlib.h"


long long int rem;
long long int ms1;
long long int unixtime;
using namespace std;
const char* Filenames;

int main(void) {

        int system(const char *command);
        int x;
        struct timeval tp1;

        rem = 5;
while (rem != 0) {
        gettimeofday(&tp1, NULL);
        ms1 = tp1.tv_sec * 1000ll  + tp1.tv_usec / 1000ll;
        rem  = ms1 % 10000;
}

for (x=0; x<3; x++){
        pid_t pid=fork();

if (pid==0){
        execl("/home/pi/odas/bin/odaslive", "/home/pi/odas/bin/odaslive", "-vc", "/home/pi/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg", (char *)NULL);
        exit(127);

} else {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(15000));
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
}
        gettimeofday(&tp1, NULL);
        unixtime = tp1.tv_sec  + tp1.tv_usec / 1000000ll;

        std::string name1 = "/home/pi/matrix_creator_explore/postfiltered/postfiltered1_";
        std::string name2 = ".raw";
        std::string result1;
        result1 = name1 + std::to_string(unixtime) + name2;
        const char *cstr = result1.c_str();
        rename ("/home/pi/matrix_creator_explore/postfiltered.raw", cstr);

        std::string name3 = "/home/pi/matrix_creator_explore/tracked/tracked1_";
        std::string name4 = ".raw";
        std::string result2;
        result2 = name3 + std::to_string(unixtime) + name4;
        const char *cstr1 = result2.c_str();
        rename ("/home/pi/matrix_creator_explore/tracked.raw", cstr1);

     
        struct stat buf;
        stat( cstr,&buf);
        printf ("\n %i \n", buf.st_size);


}
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the `stat()` and `truncate()` syscalls. But I'm also curious as to what you were expecting to achieve by using `system()` to spawn `mv` ***in the background***, then sleeping for some time (obviously crossing your fingers that the background task would finish). This is like starting the coffee maker and leaving the room, planning on returning some time later hoping that the coffee is ready, instead of simply standing next to the coffeemaker until it's done, and picking up the cup of joe right away. Oh and you can `rename` everything yourself. No need for `mv`.

Comment: I'm using a open source program and this C-file im writing calls that program in the linux terminal

Comment: What this ends up accomplishing is: forking a child process. The child process runs `/bin/bash`. `/bin/bash` executes all commands in `$HOME/.profile`, the parses its arguments, forks a second child process, that loads the `mv` command, which parses the command line, and renames the file with a lot of fanfare. The alternative approach is calling `rename()` instead of doing all that, and renaming the file immediately. Which approach do you think makes more sense? The linux terminal is not there to be "programmed" by something, only to run manually entered commands, or scripts.

Comment: The program im running saves the file to the directory it was called from. what ive written works (minus the audio file trimming) but Im sure there's much better ways to do it (the whole c file is in the description now).

Comment: Nothing about the program saving "the file to the directory it was called from" requires this convoluted way to rename a file. The only reason it works, for now, is because nothing happens to be going on at the same time this is happening. But if the system happens to be very slow at the given moment, because of some background process, and the `mv` command fails to complete within 500 milliseconds (since nothing you've done requires it to be so), everything above will break horribly.

Comment: Hmm, you are very right about system(). i have removed it from my code (updated above). Im having problems with stat() as it does not correlate to the size my computer says the files are reliably.

Comment: `stat()` gives the file size, modification timestamp, and other attributes. Without any additional details, nothing further can be said about it.

Comment: It was a problem with calling stat before waiting for the parent to kill the child, it works now thanks.